# colimit of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

How can one construct the colimit of a general diagram of groups?

On the first page of Serre's *Trees* (English translation) it says [$G_i$'s are arbitrarily indexed input groups and $F_{ij}$'s sets of maps $G_i\to G_j$]:

> Existence is easy. One can, for example, define $G$ by generators and relations; one takes the generating family to be the disjoint union of those for the $G_i$; as relations, on the one hand the $xyz^{-1}$ where $x,y,z$ belong to the same $G_i$ and $z=xy$ in $G_i$, on the other hand the $xy^{-1}$ where $x\in G_i$, $y\in G_j$ and $y=f(x)$ for at least one $f\in F_{ij}$.

My understanding of this is we start with the free group on a disjoint union of generating sets for the inputs. But then, it seems like we can only quotient the relations described, for values $x, y, z$ in the generating sets. What if my generating set for $G_i$ contains distinct $x, y, z, t$ such that $xyz = t$ in $G_i$? Then we should have $xyz = t$ in $G$, but I don't see why we do.

Comment: You have $xyz=t$ in $G$ because he is **explicitly** saying that you take as relations things like $xyz^{-1}$ where $x,y,z$ belong to the same $G_i$ and $z=xy$. Note that he is not saying $x,y,z$ are *generators*, they are arbitrary elements of $G_i$. You express $x$, $y$, and $z$ in terms of the generators, and then you add the relation given by $xyz^{-1}$, written out in terms of the generators. For $xyz=t$, you have $x'zt^{-1}$, where $x'=xy$. Same with the expression $xy^{-1}$; you write it out in terms of the generators you took.

Comment: So you can in fact take the free group on the disjoint union of the underlying sets of the $G_i$, and then your relations are just the multiplication table of the $G_i$s together with the identifying relations given by the structure morphisms.